# Awk compare 2 files and match 2 columns, get % difference between column 3s

Tags: awk

I have 2 files, with the formatting below.  I am trying to compare lines where columns 1 and 2 match and then get the difference in the 2 #'s that are in column 3.

if file 2 column 3 is greater than file1 column 3, i would like a + at the end of the row
if file2 column is less than file 1 column 3, i would like a - at the end of the row
if either file column 3 is 0 i would like a * at the end of the row.

I only want to print lines where the difference between the 2 columns is > 15%

file1

```
abc,1,472
abc,2,536
abc,3,652
abc,4,512
abc,5,474
abc,6,266
abc,7,520
def,1,954
def,9,538
def,10,136
def,11,341
def,12,183
def,13,1209
def,14,365
def,15,536
def,16,979
def,17,0
xyz,1,547
xyz,19,0
xyz,20,0
xyz,21,0
xyz,22,0
xyz,23,0
xyz,24,0
```

File 2

```
abc,1,456
abc,2,533
abc,3,643
abc,4,444
abc,5,124
abc,6,255
abc,7,520
def,1,954
def,9,538
def,10,435
def,11,341
def,12,155
def,13,1209
def,14,365
def,15,536
def,16,979
def,17,0
xyz,1,547
xyz,19,124
xyz,20,0
xyz,21,0
xyz,22,0
xyz,23,0
xyz,24,0
```

expected output

```
abc,5,474,124,74%,-     // (474-124)/474 = 74%
def,10,136,435,31%,+.   // (435-136)/474 = 69%
xyz,19,0,124,100%,*.    // either file has 0 , print 100% and *
```

I have tried multiple iterations of this but cannot seem to get the formatting to work.

```
  awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]; next ;b[$1,$2,$3]; next} $1,$2 in a {if ($3>b[$3]) {Q=((b[$3]/$3) *100)) {print Q,$0 }} else if (b[$3]>$3) {Q=(($3/b[$3]) *100)){print Q,$0 }}' file1 file2
```

i get this error
^ unexpected newline or end of string

also tried variations on this line but i cannot figure out the division by 0 error

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]; next ;b[$1,$2,$3]; next} $1,$2 in a {if ((Q=(b[$3]/$3) > 15) || (Q=($3/b[$3])) > 15 ){print Q,$0}}' file1 file2 
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file2 FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Comment: `the difference between the 2 columns is > 15%` 15% of what?

Comment: of each other, lower # divided by higher #. 124/474 = 26%

Comment: thanks, i think my math is off, i think this line abc,5,474,124,26%,-
should be abc,5,474,124,74%,-  = 474-124 / 474 = 74%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to handle if the denominator is zero in the base case, since you cannot find the relative change in that case, you need to report absolute change.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{k=$1 FS $2}
            FNR==NR {a[k]=$3; next}
            k in a  {if(a[k]) q=$3/a[k]-1;
                     else if($3) zero=1
                     else q=0
                     plus=q>0.15
                     minus=q<-0.15
                     q=q<0?-q:q; 
                     if(zero) plus=minus=0
                     if(plus || minus || zero)
                       print k,a[k],$3,(zero?100:int(100*q))"%",(plus?"+":minus?"-":"*")
                     q=zero=0}' file1 file2

abc,5,474,124,73%,-
def,10,136,435,219%,+
def,12,183,155,15%,-
xyz,19,0,124,100%,*
```

you can put this in a `diff.awk` file and run with `awk -f diff.awk file1 file2`
the file contents should be

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
{k=$1 FS $2}
 ...  the code in between
   q=zero=0}
```

note that text body is without the single quotes.  You can make it executable with the right shebang but I think this will be simpler.

Comment: I tried running, it but got about 6 different syntax errors. I think thats half my issue, i dont know awk well enough to figure out the syntax errors

Comment: @chadb Above code seems to run just fine. I tested with 4 different awks.

Comment: Now tested, it doesn't match your output, but I don't think your computations are right or doing something else than what you specified.

Comment: thanks, do i need to do something special to make it all in one line? i will try again, i edited the expected output above, you were right my math was off.

Comment: you need semicolons between statements if there in no newline.  Why do you need one line?  Is it a competition?  This can be simplified a little bit but still not going to fit naturally a one-liner due to complex logic.

Comment: @karakfa one more question, how would i turn this into a standalone script,  tried putting BEGIN { } in before it and making it standalone but that didnt work.